# Guinsoo's Rageblade on Tryndamere

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been trying out Tryndamere on the top lane lately and I've had quite some success with him. Someone brought to my attention, daring me to try out Rageblade on Tryndamere as my second item. I did try it out and it's really powerful indeed.

What I would like to know is the pros and cons of the item, specifically on tryndamere. And if it's indeed a good item, what item should it replace in my final build.

My current final build, most of the time goes as follows: Boots of Swiftness, Phantom Dancer, Essence Reaver, Infinity Edge, Youmuu's Ghostblade, Bloodthirster.

Comment: If you wanted to go even further you could go Hextech Gunblade as well. I don't play Tryndamere but I've seen it done and it seemed to work well. As to what item to replace, what about Essence Reaver? Because the mana restoring passive is not going to be helping Tryn any time soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pros:

Makes him stronger in long, drawn out fights since it allows you to fully stack it

Gives him a better *1v1 potential* and *split-pushing* threat, which is pretty much what the champion is all about

Increases your *AOE*(Area of Effect) in Teamfights or 2v1's

Gives you more *waveclear* (Same has increasing Split-pushing capability)

Cons:

Doesn't provide you any real stat( You have to Auto-Attack to gain the benefits)

Pretty much only increases what he is already good at(2v1 , split-push threat), at the cost of one item and doesn't cover any of his **weaknesses**( Heavy CC, being targeted or picked off)

**Overall**:

While it isn't the worst Item for him, personally i wouldn't do it unless i was really fed already, feel that a Sterak's or Maw would be better to provide you with more *survivability* in a TeamFight or in a 3v1 situation

Regarding your final Build :

I think you are going a bit too **overkill** on the Damage, you don't need Essence Reaver or BloodThirster, my personal favorite build for him is:

Blade of the Ruined King, Stattik Shiv, Infinity Edge(if ahead) or Ravenous Hydra( If im going for split push), a Sterak's, and then some Situational Items, if they have lots of **CC** (Crowd Control), i would go for Mercurial Scimitar, if they have Tanks i would go for a Lord Dominik's Regard, if they have Squish i would go for more damage, all Depends on the comp you are playing agaisnt really

If you really want to replace Guinsoo's onto your final build, just remove Essence Reaver, it doesn't benefit you has much has the Guinsoo, although i don't completely agree with your **Overkill** damage build, but hey, opinions